Embedding sound clips in posts using Soundcloud
I wanted to ask if it is possible to have an embedded audio player like Soundcloud in Chinese SE, as implemented in Music SE or Video SE .
A user said here:

Embedding existing SoundCloud clips is possible on Music.SE (and possibly other sites); it should be trivial to add that to other sites on an as-needed basis. – goldPseudo Oct 9 '14 at 22:16

I think it is potentially a very useful feature for sharing pronunciation samples, allowing for high quality and instructive answers. Currently, pronunciation is usually discussed in writing but this is a very poor way of transmitting the information. On the other hand, I tried answering pronunciation with some audio samples in https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39231/25265
, but without the Soundcloud embedding this is still not very practical.
EDIT: What is the decision? How many votes should be required to apply this change?

We can see if your proposal here gets any traction first and then go from there.


EDIT: What is the decision? How many votes should be required to apply this change?

I'll tell you what I can (which isn't much): there is no decision (yet).  It cannot happen without Stack Exchange staff getting involved, and they've always got a zillion things going on.  It will likely take a long time (probably years), even with widespread community support.
A lot of feature requests simply don't get decisions: even if they're good ideas, other feature requests get prioritized.  This feature request is competing with pinyin support, which was requested 6 years, 8 months ago, and has been requested multiple times over the years.  Searching for [feature-request] [status-completed] shows there was only 3 implemented feature requests over the lifetime of the site, and only one involved Stack Exchange staff.
I wouldn't mind this feature, but realistically we should act as if it's not going to be implemented.  E.g. try to find a workaround (e.g., an off-site mp3 repository).
We could draw more attention to it (e.g. by featuring it, asking on meta.SE, and adding the status-review tag), but I wouldn't want to draw attention away from pinyin support.

Ok, I understand! Though it seems this feature would be straightforward to implement (it is already developed on other SE sites), instead of having to develop it (as might be the case with the pinyin support).
